# mysql 2 table diffrents

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 table OpenOrder and OpenOrderTemp in mysql 8 (last version ) the both table    have some column id , orderid etc.. (are identical structure) i insert in OpenOrderTemp  some data and  i want compare with first table OpenOrder by only orderid , i create  this SQL syntax

```
SELECT orderid FROM OpenOrder MINUS SELECT orderid FROM OpenOrderTemp;
```

but unfurtunally return me this error

> Error SQL [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
> the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'SELECT orderid FROM OpenOrderTemp' at line 1

with the occasion I ask which is the sql string that has the best speed performance for comparing two tables? , i know join is not  a good choice , thanks  again at  all

Comment: PLease add sample data and expected result

Comment: The MINUS operator is not supported in all SQL databases. It can used in databases such as Oracle.  For databases such as SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and SQLite, use the EXCEPT operator to perform this type of query. (source [1](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php), [2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-minus-operator/) ).

Answer (score 1):

The MINUS operator is not supported in all SQL databases. It can used in databases such as [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm).

For databases such as [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-select.html), and [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html), use the EXCEPT operator to perform this type of query.

Because you are using MySQL, you have to do something like this:

```
SELECT OpenOrder.orderid 
FROM OpenOrder 
LEFT JOIN OpenOrderTemp ON OpenOrder.orderid = OpenOrderTemp.orderid
WHERE OpenOrderTemp.orderid IS NULL;
```

Comment: thanks for rply  ,  i use  you sql but return me Error SQL [1052] [23000]: Column 'orderid' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: sorry, forgot to specify which `orderid` should be selected. This is solved adding `OpenOrder.` before the selected field to make you select the field form the table `OpenOrder`.

Comment: thanks  another  question about this   if  i want  select  other orderid ,  suppose  want also id column i must SELECT OpenOrder.orderid.id  ???? , sorry i usally do simple select

Comment: It should be in the form "<tablename>.<columnname>", so `OpenOrder.id`.